# How to write date filter in MDX where clause?

Tags: t-sql, mdx

I am new to MDX. Could please suggest how to write below T-SQL query in MDX Query language.

T-SQL:

```
    SELECT wp.date,Sum(wp.bbls_oil)   
         AS BBLSOIL_TOTAL,Sum(wp.bbls_water) 
         AS BBLSWATER_TOTAL,Sum(wp.mcf_prod) 
         AS MCF_PROD_TOTAL,Sum(wp.vent_flare)
        AS VENT_FLARE_TOTAL 
    FROM  well_prod_bst_horiz_og_2_yrs wp, well_index wi
    WHERE wp.fileno = wi.fileno 
      AND wp.date <= :startDate 
      AND wp.date >= :endDate
      AND wi.apino IN (:wellids) 
   GROUP BY wp.date ORDER BY wp.date ASC";
```

In the above query, Start and End date values are supplied dynamically.

Comment: For dynamic parameters, this depends on the environment from which you call the MDX statement. Which environment do you use? Reporting Services? A custom C# program? Integration Services ADO.net data source? SQL Server OpenQuery? Other?

Comment: I am calling these queries in my java based web application. Write a MDX statement and pass to OLAP statement object and then called excuteQuery() method. This way am getting results and construct JSON object based on the result and then pass this JSON object to highcharts data object.

Comment: In this case, why do you not just put the parameter values into the MDX statement directly? As probably, the keys are controlled by your application, I would not think there is much SQL (or MDX) injection potential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have measures named `BBLSOIL`, `BBLSWATER`, `MCF_PROD`, and `VENT_FLARE_TOTAL` and your date attribute is named `[Date].[Date]`, and your `:startDate` contains `[Date].[Date].&[20120101]` and your `:endDate` contains `[Date].[Date].&[20141231]`, and your cube is named `Name of your Cube` you would write

```
SELECT {
       Measures.[BBLSOIL],
       Measures.[BBLSWATER],
       Measures.[MCF_PROD],
       Measures.[VENT_FLARE_TOTAL]
       }
       ON COLUMNS,

       [Date].[Date].&[20120101] : [Date].[Date].&[20141231]
       ON ROWS
  FROM [Name of your Cube]
```

i. e. you put an MDX set containing the list of required measures on the columns axis and you put a range (specified by `:`) on the rows axis. Aggregations like `Sum` and `GROUP BY` are not necessary inn MDX, these are handled by the cube definition.